# Constraints on pyrotechnic explosives that won't detonate spontaneously at 500 °C when landing on Venus?

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat, temperature, explosives, pyrotechnics

The Space Exploration SE question [Premature detonation of explosive bolts when landing on hot Venus?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53690/12102) explains the need for and widespread use of [pyrotechnic fasteners and cable cutters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrotechnic_fastener) for Mars landers and elsewhere in spaceflight, and points out that Venus' atmosphere is already 75 °C and 1 atmosphere at an altitude of 50 km and roughly 500 °C and a dense 90 bar supercritical fluid at the surface.

So anything on the outside of a lander is going to get hot during the long descent to the surface in this thick soup.

**Questions:** What are the *chemical and physical constrains* on reliable, easily to electrically detonate explosives for pyrotechnic devices that will prevent them from spontaneously detonating at 500 °C when landing on Venus? Are there any realistic, potential candidates?

For example; do we need reactions that are less exothermic? Or a higher barrier between initial and final states? Or a lower density so that below some critical temperature an occasional molecule "exploding" doesn't trigger the next one so easily?

---

These examples are on Mars, not Venus. Click for larger

[image: Perseverance cut cables for landing] [image: Fused picture of rover's top after landing]

**left:** From [How were Perseverance's cables "cut" after touching down?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50268/12102) in Space Exploration SE **right** from [this answer there](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/50363/12102). [source: NASA/JPL-Caltech](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/ZRF_0003_0667219606_000FDR_N0010052AUT_04096_034085J01) and [source: NASA/JPL-Caltech](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/ZRF_0003_0667218267_000FDR_N0010052AUT_04096_034085J01)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did the first landing on Venus manage the feat? I ask because it is not clear that what works well on the thin Martian atmosphere would be adaptable for the “thick soup” Venusian atmosphere.

Comment: @EdV Good question! There is an answer posted on my linked question. Those pyrotechnic devices were kept internal to the craft, which was "chilled" before atmospheric entry and insulated thereby allowing its electronics to work as well, for a few hours. That was a long time ago. In the future Venus landers and rovers will use some combination of (perhaps) refrigeration and [high band gap/temperature semiconductors](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20096) My question here is purely about the chemistry of potential 500 °C pyrotechnics, whether or not they will actually be used.

Comment: @EdV Just fyi; per that answer, they used special cords on the parachute that held it partially closed so it would fall very fast until reaching 200 °C when the parachute opened fully to avoid crashing. The fast fall was to shorten the time to the surface so that more of its limited "chill time" would happen after landing.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the information! I was thinking some sort of insulated internal “shotgun” mechanism, maybe with small shaped charges, could blow the bolts off or out. Seems like that is essentially what was done. So how about using two substances that are thermally stable, but explode on contact? Ram them together at the right locations and take out the bolts.

Comment: @EdV Interesting thought, if it has a chance of working please consider describing it in an answer post!

Comment: I suspect NH4NO3 based explosive may work. Per the Texas City disaster, just heating NH4NO3 may not result in an explosion (complex product range as a function temperature, which may be favorable in your situation). Also, N2O dissolved in fuel is an idea where N2O is more electrostatically given to explode than just by heating (but does result in extremely high temperatures on detonating, vaporizing metal).

Comment: Because oil wells reach high temperature at depth, there are special explosives, e.g. https://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2010/0006193.html . As you mention, wide-band-gap semiconductors such as SiC first received use in well loggers. Interesting - "As above, so below."

Comment: The question is rather which explosive does not decompose/sublimate and possibly not even melt at 500 °C?

Comment: @Poutnik why would melting have to be explicitly excluded? For the purposes of this question it only needs to work at hight temperature, perhaps melting could be required to produce the explosive. What I've asked about here is *how to avoid the problem of spontaneous explosion* at that 500 °C.

Comment: possibly does not mean have to. I had in mind eventual phase change may affect the functionality of explosive device. But thermal  degradation along high T safety are the major concerns.

Comment: @Poutnik yes, it could activate it for example, or melt two precursors that then mixed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_explosive

Comment: Sure, binary explosives are safer way.  But generally, even if binary, energy rich molecules do not like high temperatures.

Comment: it would have to be based on solid salts, like barium nitrate + aluminium powder

Comment: @FrancisL. I think that if you explain why in an answer it might be well-received. The question asks about constraints and it seems you've given that some careful consideration.

Comment: How small could a thermobaric explosive be made? Basically, use a burst of oxygen gas to get flammable particulates suspended in a very small compustion chamber and then use a spark plug to ignite, sending the bolt-cutting ‘piston’ to do its job. Basically just a flour mill explosion in miniature.

Comment: @EdV that's excellent, a mini-space-[grain silo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_explosion#Sources_of_dust) explosive bolt/[frangible nut](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50930/12102) I love it! Better file the patent ASAP (*seriously!*) and/or post an answer.

Comment: When I was writing the comment, I had grain silo first and then changed it to flour mill. But it really does not answer your actual question about pyrotechnics and constraints, etc. I don’t much care about the rep stuff, so if someone else wants to develop (or elaborate) and post an actual answer, it is fine with me. By the way, I have one (now expired, I think) patent that got me nothing but interaction with a lawyer. I will pass on doing that again.

Comment: @EdV yes I know the experience of which you speak and would personally "[run away](https://youtube.com/watch?v=MUG9VzHoEoc)" if ever asked again to write something up as a patent, but this is a *really cool* (or in this case *hot*) idea no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic compounds as a general rule have greater bond strength than covalently bound molecules. This makes them more heat resistant, therefore it seems likely that a binary explosive consisting of an oxidizer salt and a fuel would be the way to go.

Since you don't want the explosive to change phases during the mission, since it could leak or unmix, you'd want a salt with melting temperature above 500 °C, the same goes for fuel.

One possibility would be barium nitrate and powdered aluminium mixture.

Comment: The trouble could be safety of their mixture, not to be trigerred prematurely, as 500 °C is a lot.

Comment: I don't doubt your answer, is it possible though to add some reference about reactions between barium nitrate and powdered aluminium for completeness? *Thanks!*

Comment: I can only provide a link to a video with someone testing it out https://youtu.be/BB4Nj7ZkUKw